# DRY toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's an way to "DRY" this code below? I mean, don't repeat `click(function())` for each element (balance and orders extract).

```
 $("#cash-extract, #balance-extract, #orders-extract").hide();
    $("#cash-history").click(function() {
        $("#cash-extract").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    })
```

Thank you!

HTML

```
<h3 id="cash-history">title</h3>
    <div id="cash-extract">
</div>
<h3 id="balance-history">title</h3>
    <div id="balance-extract">
</div>
<h3 id="orders-history">title</h3>
    <div id="orders-extract">
</div>
```

Comment: Add a common class for all elements and select by this class.

Comment: post the markup structure too.

Comment: what are the elements to toggle

Comment: How `cash-history` element is related to `cash-extract`?

Comment: @Jospeh `<h3>` can't be closed with `</div>`.

Comment: how it can repeat to all elements ???

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3aL650uq/1/

Comment: @Jai My markup code is very big and I code a fast example. I'm sorry, my mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two things:

1. Use a common class name to bind the event like `.cash`.
2. You can make use of `data-*` attribute to store the target elem like `data-target="cash-target"`.

---

See this:

```
<button class='cash' data-target='cash-extract'>cash history</button>

<div id='cash-extract'>Cash history.</div>
```

Now you can connect it with this:

```
$('.cash').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('#'+target).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
});
```

---

If you don't want to restructure it you can use `.next()` to target it and do this:

```
$("#cash-history, #balance-history, #orders-history").click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
});
```

Comment: You only is considering cash element. I need to be able to click in cash, orders and balance history (title) and after clickd, show the extract. I updated my post!

Comment: As per current posted structure you can target the element with `.next()` to fadeToggle.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind to multiple dom elements:

```
 $("#cash-extract, #balance-extract, #orders-extract").hide();
     $("#cash-history, #balance-history, #orders-history").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];
        $('#'+id+'-extract').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });
```

or:

```
$("#cash-history, #balance-history, #orders-history").click(function() {
            $("#cash-extract, #balance-extract, #orders-extract").hide();
            $(this).next().fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        });
```

or keep only one extract open:

```
  $("#cash-history, #balance-history, #orders-history").click(function() {
            $("#cash-extract, #balance-extract, #orders-extract").hide();
            $(this).next().fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        });
```

Comment: where is `#cash-history`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.not()`  to deselect all `ID`'s or `class` which you dont want to `click`

```
$("#cash-extract, #balance-extract, #orders-extract").hide();
        $("#cash-history").not("mention all IDS here to exclude").click(function() {
            $("#cash-extract").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
        })
```